# C# showing double output

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Questions : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private bool InstanceFieldsInitialized = false;

    private Questions()
    {
        if (!InstanceFieldsInitialized)
        {
            InitializeInstanceFields();
            InstanceFieldsInitialized = true;
        }
    }

    private void InitializeInstanceFields()
    {
        r = User.Identity.Name;
    }

    private ArrayList @params = new ArrayList();
    string r;
    private ArrayList pklist = new ArrayList();

    //Dynamically Loads the Questions based off of the table.
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //Questions Loaded

        string proc = "Question_Select";
        SqlConnection QuestionsConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Feedback-ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand QuestionsCommand = new SqlCommand(proc, QuestionsConnection);
        QuestionsCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(QuestionsCommand);
        DataTable vTable = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(vTable);




        Table detailsTable = new Table();
        detailsTable.CellSpacing = 10;
        var i = 0;

        foreach (DataRow row in vTable.Rows)
        {
            var value = vTable.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
            TableCell tCell1 = new TableCell();
            TableCell tCell2 = new TableCell();
            var pk = vTable.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            pklist.add(pk);

            Label myLabel = new Label();

            myLabel.CssClass = "bold";

            TextBox myText = new TextBox();

            myText.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
            myText.Columns = 40;
            myText.Rows = 4;
            myText.ID = "Box" + i;
            @params.add(myText.ID);

            myLabel.Text = string.Format("{0}. {1}", i + 1, value);
            tCell1.Controls.Add(myLabel);
            tCell2.Controls.Add(myText);
            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell1);
            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell2);

            detailsTable.Rows.Add(tRow);
            i += 1;
        }
        Panel1.Controls.Add(detailsTable);

    }


    //INSTANT C# WARNING: Strict 'Handles' conversion only applies to fields declared in the same class - the event will be wired in 'SubscribeToEvents':
    //ORIGINAL LINE: Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //When a survey is completed, this method checks to see who completed the survey and insert them into a table.
        string proc2 = "User_Insert";
        SqlConnection ResponsesConnection2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Feedback-ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand ResponsesCommand2 = new SqlCommand(proc2, ResponsesConnection2);
        ResponsesCommand2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        ResponsesCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", r);
        ResponsesConnection2.Open();
        ResponsesConnection2 = (SqlConnection)ResponsesCommand2.ExecuteScalar();

        //   Establish connection and set up command to use stored procedure
        string proc = "Responses_Insert";
        SqlConnection ResponsesConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Feedback-ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand ResponsesCommand = new SqlCommand(proc, ResponsesConnection);
        ResponsesCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        ResponsesConnection.Open();

       <--HERE IS WHERE I THINK THE PROBLEM IS-->
        ***var i = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < @params.ToString().Count(); a++)
        {
            ResponsesCommand.Parameters.Clear();
            TextBox textbox = Panel1.FindControl(@params.ToString().ElementAt(a).ToString()) as TextBox;
            ResponsesCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionID", pklist.ToString().ElementAt(i).ToString());
            ResponsesCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@response", textbox.Text);
            ResponsesCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", r);
            ResponsesConnection = (SqlConnection)ResponsesCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            i += 1;***

        }


        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox("Thank you for completing the survey.", Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground, "Survey Complete");



        Response.Redirect("../../../Default.aspx");

    }
    //Button to see if a person has chosen to be marked annonymous.
    //INSTANT C# WARNING: Strict 'Handles' conversion only applies to fields declared in the same class - the event will be wired in 'SubscribeToEvents':
    //ORIGINAL LINE: Protected Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Checkbox1.CheckedChanged
    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Checkbox1.Checked == false)
        {
            r = User.Identity.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            r = "Anonymous";
        }
    }
}
```

}

I need a little help. My code shows double output when ran. Had multiple choices to use var, object, or dynamic using code converters. Chose var but it still outputs double. When debugger is ran shows no errors.

Comment: What do you mean by double output?

Comment: Debuggers do not show errors.  Debuggers help ***you*** find the errors.  But you do the finding.

Comment: There is more than double output wrong with your code...

Comment: please be more specific. Which method is giving the double output, how did you test it? what exactly is the code meant to do? it is a lot of code, and almost no comments. Do you expect us to understand it rightaway when reading?

Comment: It is printing the questions twice. I have 6 questions, it shows 1-6 then 1-6 again

Answer (score 1):

I would question whether you need .ToString() in the following (in the for loop):

```
a < @params.ToString().Count()
```

It seems like you probably just want the number of items in the @params list, so try replacing the above with the following:

```
a < @params.Count
```

That may fix your problem of the loop executing the wrong number of times. If so, then similarly within the loop body you probably shouldn't be using .ToString() in either of these:

```
@params.ToString().ElementAt(a)
pklist.ToString().ElementAt(i)
```

If your loop still seems to be executing too many times, then you should try stepping through it in the debugger or adding print statements (Console.WriteLine) to print the variable values for each iteration of the loop and better understand what it's doing.